# ASP.NET / LINQ / EF: Async on custom distinct comparer class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm using .NET Core with EF Core.

I use a custom comparer class like this to achieve a distinct result on my query:

```
var filterResult = (from c in MyDBContext.Table1

                     join mt in MyDBContext.Table2
                     on c.ID equals mt.ID

                     select new MyModel
                     {
                         ID = c.ID,
                         Description = c.Description
                     }

                    )
                    .ToList()
                    .Distinct(new MyComparer())
                    .Take(takeThis);
```

This is what the comparer class looks like:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyModel>
{

    public bool Equals(MyModel x, MyModel y)
    {

        return x.ID == y.ID;

    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyModel obj)
    {

        return obj == null ? 0 : obj.ID;

    }

}
```

This works, but I want to improve it's performance by trying to run `distinct()` before `ToList()` to avoid grabbing the entire table (and also implement async).

This is my goal:

```
var filterResult = await (from c in MyDBContext.Table1

                     join mt in MyDBContext.Table2
                     on c.ID equals mt.ID

                     select new MyModel
                     {
                         ID = c.ID,
                         Description = c.Description
                     }

                    )
                    .Distinct(new MyComparer())
                    .Take(takeThis)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Using this, I get an `NotSupportedException` exception. So I tried to do the following:

```
.Distinct(new MyComparer())
.Take(takeThis)
.ToList();
```

But that also gives me a `NotSupportedException` exception.

How do I change my code to avoid having to run `ToList()` before distinct?

Comment: I do not think this is possible, anything before ToListAsync will try to execute on sql server. It will not be able to translate you MyComparer implementation. Another option might be to group the result by id then select the first value of each before doing the ToList

Comment: Thanks Martin! What would such an implementation look like? Something along the lines of `.GroupBy(c => c.D).Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault()).Take(takeThis).ToListAsync();` ?

Comment: Exactly yes. That's what I had in mind without being able to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Distinct before query materialization (.ToList()) in the context of EF query will result in EF tring to translate the code to SQL Query, but EF is not that powerfull to translate any c# method to SQL query, in the following case the Comparer logic.

As alternative to this query i will suggest you to use the following query:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
.Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault())
.OrderBy(x => x.ID)
.Take(() => ....)
.ToListAsync()
```

This will create groups for entities with same ID's and then from each group it will select the first one and using order by will keep the result consistent for the query.